# Is »für« or »vor« redundant in this sentence from »Der Spiegel«?

Tags: preposition, expression

The below paragraph appears in the article “[Schlacht um Deir al-Sor. 100.000 Syrer im Würgegriff des IS](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/syrien-islamischer-staat-steht-vor-der-eroberung-von-deir-al-sor-a-1130409.html)” from *Der Spiegel*:

> *Die drohende Einnahme der Stadt stellt damit auch **für** die US-Armee **vor** ein Dilemma*: Greift sie gar nicht oder zu zögerlich
>   gegen den IS ein, gefährdet sie das Leben von Tausenden Menschen, die
>   denn dem IS in die Hände fallen. Schlägt sie den IS mit ihren
>   Luftangriffen zurück, stärkt sie aber gleichzeitig die Position des
>   Assad-Regimes und dessen Verbündeten Russland. Indirekt würde
>   Washington damit seinen Gegnern in Syrien helfen.

It seems to me that *für* is redundant in the first sentence of the paragraph. Even without *vor* (but still with *für*) the sentence would seem OK. So, is the original sentence correct, or is one, or both, of my alternative versions of the sentence correct:

> Die drohende Einnahme der Stadt stellt damit auch die US-Armee **vor** ein Dilemma...
>
> Die drohende Einnahme der Stadt stellt damit auch **für** die US-Armee ein Dilemma...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it seems like they could not decide whether they wanted to use the sentence as

> Die drohende Einnahme der Stadt stellt damit auch die US-Armee **vor** ein Dilemma.

or

> Die drohende Einnahme der Stadt stellt damit auch **für** die US-Armee ein Dilemma **dar**.

and they ended up with a mixture of both. That happens quite often in newspapers.

Notice that you need *dar* as part of the verb *darstellen* in the second version of the sentence.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me, the sentence is wrong.
Your first version of the sentence is correct.
The second version should be:

> Die drohende Einnahme der Stadt stellt damit auch für die US-Armee ein Dilemma dar...

Comment: Yep - the "für" seems to be a forgotten remnant of a former version. It's just wrong.